# Ruby: Hash - Sorting/Adjusting Duplicate Values and Storing Back with Key?

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash, duplicates

So I am having a bit of an issue here deciding what tools to use to solve this problem. It is a rather complex problem but I will do my best to describe it.

At the moment I have a relationship of values gathered and stored in a hash. The hash way of doing things can be changed to anything else that you think is better. I just used hash for now to keep the relationship as it is important.

So something like:

```
key  -> value

1456 -> 1
1532 -> 50
1892 -> 2
1092 -> 5
1487 -> 10
5641 -> 5
1234 -> 2
1687 -> 1
```

My goal here is to take the values, and *adjust* them so that there are no duplicates, and then place the adjusted values back in their appropriate relationship with the key. Basically I do not want the duplicate values deleted, I want them changed in a way so that there are no duplicates anymore.
(duplicates in example above are: 1 and 2)

As a side note here is a summary of a few important things to keep in mind for my situation:

- the relationship between the key-value pairs (must always know which value is for what key)
- not having any duplicate values
- you cannot delete a key-value pair, only change the value.
- the order of values from lowest to highest is important

Normally I would have no trouble sorting an array of integers, but in this case it is the relationship with other values that is giving me a lot of trouble with this.

Comment: What are the rules to change a value to make it unique?

Comment: I think I understand.  Would the following qualify as a solution: `{ 1456 => 1, 1532 => 50, 1892 => 3, 1092 => 5, 1487 => 10, 5641 => 5, 1234 => 4, 1687 => 2}`?  What about `{ 1456 => 1, 1532 => 7, 1892 => 3, 1092 => 5, 1487 => 6, 5641 => 5, 1234 => 4, 1687 => 2}`? Please give a yes/no answer to each question. By the way, this is how you should have written your hash.

Comment: Basically make sure the value stays in its relative order with the other numbers, so basically for the values: 1 2 2 4, the key-value pairs with value 2 must always stay in their relative position with key-value pairs with values 1 and 4 (i hope that made sense)...

Comment: So if you have 1,2,2,3,50, can this simply go to 1,2,3,4,5, or do you need to keep the 50: 1,2,3,4,50?

Comment: Cary: Close, except I see two values = 5 in each instance, and we want to avoid duplicate values.
Matt: You do not need to keep the fifty, just need to keep the order relative (so both are correct)

Comment: I missed that, but in my second question I really was asking if you could just change them all, as @Matt has also asked.  Changing them all to just a ranking would be very easy.  If you can't do that, what about `{1 => 1, 2 =>1, 3 => 2}`?

Comment: Hashes aren't really ordered data types. You might consider a 2xN array.

Comment: Yes you can change them all, as I said so long as you keep the relative order of the values, so in another example: {123 => 1, 234 => 2, 456 => 2} can turn into {123 => 20, 234 => 30, 456 => 40} to get rid of duplicates and maintain order :)

Comment: This makes no sense. You need to values to be unique, but it doesn't matter what they are? Why not just use an array of the keys? It has ordering as one of the features of the data structure.

Comment: @mbantch, as I'm sure you know, hashes have preserved insertion order since v1.9.  I was skeptical about the value of that, but it proved useful in an answer I gave recently.  I used a hash for substitutions, where the order of substitution was important.

Comment: The situation is a little odd I'll admit, I didn't set this problem up personally, but the values you see for the key-value pairs were already made and needed to be adjusted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input = { 1456 => 1,
  1532 => 50,
  1892 => 2,
  1092 => 5,
  1487 => 10,
  5641 => 5,
  1234 => 2,
  1687 => 1 }

values = input.sort_by { |a,b| b }.map { |a,b| a }
# => [1456, 1687, 1892, 1234, 1092, 5641, 1487, 1532]
Hash[*values.flat_map.with_index(1) { |a,i| [a,i] }]
# => {1456=>1, 1687=>2, 1892=>3, 1234=>4, 1092=>5, 5641=>6, 1487=>7, 1532=>8}
```

All the necessary information is contained in the `values` array.

Comment: Considering that the values need only be distinct and preserve order, I would suggest something more interesting, like: `{1456 => "I love donuts, hmmm", 1687 => "I love donuts, hmmmm,...}`"

Comment: always interesting with donuts :)
nice, you hit it spot on, cheers!